# Cursor moveToNext() after button was clicked - getting next values

Tags: android

In my activity layout, I have 2 textviews and one button. I connect to my database and I get values using Cursor.

When activity starts, Textviews display good values, but when I click 'next' button, it doesn't change textviews text to next values in my database.

I tried to get next values using cursor.moveToNext() in my button OnClickListener, but I'm doing something wrong.

Here is the code for getting values:

```
private Cursor cursor;
private dataRepo dataRepo;
private String dataValue1;
private String dataValue2;
private TextView txtDataValue1;
private TextView txtDataValue2;
private Button btnNext;

private void getValues(long i)
{
        cursor = dataRepo.getValue(i);
        dataValue1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(VALUE_E.KEY_VALUE_NAME));
        dataValue2 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(VALUE_P.KEY_VALUE_NAME));
}
```

OnCreate:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_panel2);
dataRepo = new dataRepo(Panel2.this);
txtDataValue1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtValue1);
txtDataValue2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtValue2);
btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Next);

getValues(2);
txtDataValue1.setText(dataValue1);
txtDataValue2.setText(dataValue2);

// I think something is wrong here
btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        cursor.moveToNext();
        getValues(2);
        txtDataValue1.setText(dataValue1);
        txtDataValue2.setText(dataValue2);

    }
});
```

How can I get next values in my textviews after button is clicked?

Comment: You are alway calling `getValues(2)`. You don't need to pass any `long` to getValues. If they are in the same class, calling `cursor.getString()` will do it. Otherwise, pass the correct position. Maybe something like that `getValues(cursor.getPosition())`

Comment: Thank you, that works! I just need to use getString().